# how to put a filename from the newest file in the directory into a variable

Tags: bash, shell, variables, ls

I am making a script. i need to automate a portion that looks at all the files in the directory containing the string "HNAZXLCOM" in the name then take the newest file with that string in the name and put the filename into a variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function latest {
    if [[ $FUNCNAME == ${FUNCNAME[1]} ]]; then
        unset -v x latest files
        printf -v "$@"
    elif (($# > 2)); then
        printf '%s\n' "Usage: $FUNCNAME <glob> <varname>" 'Error: Takes at most 2 arguments. Glob defaults to *'
        return 1
    else
        if ! shopt -q nullglob; then
            typeset -f +t "$FUNCNAME"
            trap 'shopt -u nullglob; trap - RETURN' RETURN
            shopt -s nullglob
        fi

        IFS= typeset -a 'files=(${1:-*})'
        typeset latest x

        for x in "${files[@]}"; do
            [[ -d $x || $x -ot $latest ]] || latest=$x
        done

        ${2:+"$FUNCNAME"} "${2:-printf}" -- %s "$latest"
    fi
}


latest '*HNAZXLCOM*' myVar
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read you right

```
var="$(ls -t1 *HNAZXLCOM*|head -n 1)"
```

Comment: Or is it the directory containing the string, the file or filename?

Answer (score -1):

From man ls, the -t switch is relevant.  Also see the -1 switch.

```
-t     sort by modification time, newest first  
-1     list one file per line
```

The -1 switch is not relevant, because `ls` automatically writes only one line per name when outputting to a pipe.

At a command prompt, the following function will list the 13 most recent files; eg, `xt *HNAZXLCOM*` would list the 13 most recent files with that string in their names, while `xt` by itself would list the most recent files (of any pattern) in the current working directory.  Adjust the number to whatever you prefer.  Some versions of head may require `-n 13` instead of `-13`.  In your application,
`H=$(ls -t *HNAZXLCOM* | head -n 1)`
is appropriate.

```
xt () 
{ 
    date;
    ls --color -Glt --color --time-style="+%Y-%m-%d %T" $* | grep -v "/" | head -13
}
```